# How to create offline installer for node packages?

Tags: node.js, npm

I wanted to know if it's possible to just install a package globally (for ex: ExpressJS) and then when I want to add it to a specific folder/project. I can just install a copy from the global package instead of installing it from the internet again.
How do I do this?
I saw another thread here and it says to create a tarball using `npm pack` which creates a tarball file but I don't know how to install a tar.gz as a package. I'm new to npm.

The reason I need this is because my internet is metered and very slow. If possible I want to download packages only once then just reuse it again on other projects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `npm i <filename-which-ends-with.tar.tz>` eg. `npm i my-pack.tar.tz`

Comment: Where should I save my tar file? Do I specify the directory too?

Comment: No there's none, If you want to keep it global then use ```npm i -g my-pack.tar.tz```, You Can use execute this command in the same directory where the file is or prefer to specify the path.